# Google Cloud DNS and DNSSEC?

Tags: dns-hosting, dnssec, google-cloud-dns

Since Google Cloud DNS does not currently support the record types for DNSSEC, is there any way to begin implementation of DNSSEC using TXT records? If I were using Google Cloud DNS, which I am, and they currently only support record types which include SOA, A, AAAA, CNAME, MX, NS, SPF, SRV, PTR and TXT: am I able to do it while constricted to these record types? Or do I have to wait until support is hard-coded into the service?

I am just wondering because I would really like to ensure absolute integrity for my company so that I only convey realness in it's purity. =D

Answer (score 3):

[DNSSEC is now in alpha for Cloud DNS](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cloud-dns-announce/c7MD0CslHaM/5xf6RXLdCQAJ). You can [request access](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1kuZbJzi7PJCNZBoxFz90pYLRaRLkzHIzRu3-psw-EpE/viewform) for testing.

Answer (score 2):

[Internet Software Consortium, DNSSEC Look-Aside-Validation FAQ](https://dlv.isc.org/about/dnssec_records):

> DNSSEC Record Types
>
> DNSSEC adds several new record types. These automatically generated
>   by signing tools and not edited directly. However, understanding their
>   relationship to one another can help if problems occur.
>
> - DNSKEY [...]
> - RRSIG [...]
> - NSEC [...]
> - NSEC3 [...]
> - DS [...]
> - DLV [...]

So, no. But if you need the feature, you are free to use a DNS service which does support DNSSEC in one way or the other. Most mass-hosters don't yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

[DNSSEC is now in beta](https://cloud.google.com/dns/dnssec), this means is available for the public, but doesn't provide any SLA. Here is the [Configuration guide](https://cloud.google.com/dns/dnssec-config).